# Why are different functions passed to useEffect on every render in ReactJS useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-docs

I was going through the useEffect hook from [reactjs docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and I've found this statement [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#:%7E:text=Experienced%20JavaScript%20developers%20might%20notice%20that%20the%20function%20passed%20to%20useEffect%20is%20going%20to%20be%20different%20on%20every%20render.)

> Experienced JavaScript developers might notice that the function
> passed to useEffect is going to be **different on every render**.

We are passing a function to useEffect and this function is said to be different for each render. useEffect has access to both state and props, since it is inside the function component and when either of these changes, we can see that change in the function of useEffect(because of closure) right? This is not clear, because in the [next line](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#:%7E:text=This%20is%20intentional.%20In%20fact%2C%20this%20is%20what%20lets%20us%20read%20the%20count%20value%20from%20inside%20the%20effect%20without%20worrying%20about%20it%20getting%20stale.) the docs state

> This is intentional. In fact, this is what lets us read the count
> value from inside the effect without worrying about it getting stale.

To counter this, assume we have a function

```
function foo(n) {
    bar = () => {
        setTimeout(() => console.log({n}), 50);
        return n;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {n = 10}, 0);
    setTimeout(() => {n = 20}, 100);
    setTimeout(() => {n = 30}, 150);
    return bar;
}

baz = foo(1);
baz(); //prints 10
setTimeout(baz, 300); //prints 30
```

It seems that when the closure value `n` is changed, we can see that change in the `setTimeout`'s callback (and this callback isn't changed over time). So, how can the closured value(state/props) in useEffect's function become stale as mentioned in docs?

Am I missing something here? I think it's more of a JavaScript question compared to React, so I took a JavaScript example.

Comment: What do you mean the value has become stale? It's outputting `30` which is the last value it was changed to.

Comment: yes @evolutionxbox, the value is not stale, but the docs say that the function passed to useEffect is going to be different on every render to avoid stale values, and since useEffect's function is also getting the state and props as closured values, how can they be stale?

Comment: The main point to take away from the react docs is that calling `foo` will create a new function object called `bar` each time. In your example you only call `foo` once so you are not comparing like with like. The render function of class components (or the function of function components) gets called each time the component needs to be re-rendered and it is these multiple calls that will create a new function that gets passed to `useEffect` each time. In your example your one and only `baz` object is a closure which includes the one and only  `n` number

Comment: Thank you for your response @apokryfos, from what I understood, the function(or class) component gets called again when there is a state change(true) and that will create a new function in `useEffect`, but assuming the passed function is just a callback to `useEffect`, does it mean all the callback functions(event listeners etc) are created again? if yes, then why? it's not to get the updated state/props, because these functions will have them anyways. Is it due to some lost reference to the callback function? or since the values in the function are changed, it is considered a new function?

Comment: Yes all the functions are created again. It's just how JavaScript works. When you do `const a = () => {}` then each time you do that you get a new instance of a function object. You use of course use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to create a memoized callback that will remain stable across renders if you need to but the docs say you shouldn't need to do this for the callback that goes in `useEffect` and in fact they discourage it. Not entirely sure why it's discouraged, it is however much easier if you don't have to do it

Comment: Thanks a lot, @apokryfos for your response. Will a new function be created with a non-arrow function on each render? and your explanation makes total sense if a function object is created for each render, but in the ref docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs) they mentioned, _**You may not use the ref attribute on function components because they don’t have instances.**_, so I'm not sure if this is the case here, but please do let me know if I missed something here.

Comment: Function components don't have instances the same way class components do. It's a single function that technically is a function object instance but there's only one regardless of how much you reuse a function component so you can't use that as an instance. Therefore you shouldn't use `this` in function components because the context is generally undefined. Yes there are edge cases where a function component can be created multiple times but usually when you declare a function component in a module and export it to be reused it is only created once

Comment: Firstly apologies for more questions, I just want to correct the misconception I have and thank you for replying back patiently everytime, 
Just to be clear, you previously said that all functions are created on each render, does this mean that the function components by themselves are just a reference and no instances are created for them, and for the functions inside them will be created each render? Since even they are functions shouldn't they also be used by reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer a few days back, and as [@apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos)(Thank you again!) mentioned in the comments above, the program execution process is now making more sense. I want to summarize my learnings here.

Firstly, the code I considered, was not like with like comparison (in [@apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos) words) with the [React doc statements](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#detailed-explanation:%7E:text=Experienced%20JavaScript%20developers%20might%20notice%20that%20the%20function%20passed%20to%20useEffect%20is%20going%20to%20be%20different%20on%20every%20render.), and this is true. In case of static HTML + vanilla JS where the HTML button has an [event-listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) JS function, this function is declared only once and when the event occurs the same JS function is executed everytime.

The code I have given in the question is similar to this, and so when executed in console or in event listener will only be declared once.

In case of [React](https://reactjs.org/)(or any state based UI libraries/frameworks), the HTML is not static and it needs to change on [state-change](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). On the execution side (considering [React](https://reactjs.org/)), component will be created when we call it (in [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)), and the component's [function/class](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) will be executed completely from top to bottom. This means

- from all the event-handlers that doesn't deal with [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), constants to [useState's destructed elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-what-do-square-brackets-mean) and [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)'s callback functions, everything are re-initialized.
- If the parent's state changes initiate a render on its children(in normal scenarios), then the children will need to re-render themselves completely with the new props and/or new state to show the updated UI
- Considering the example in React docs ([link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#detailed-explanation)), [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with no dependencies will get executed after every render, and here it's updating the DOM by showing the current state value. Unless the callback function has the latest value of that state, it'll only print the stale value. So re-initialising the functions here is the main reason behind not having stale values in the callback functions

  ```
   function Example() {
       const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

       useEffect(() => {
       document.title = 'You clicked ${count} times';
       });
   }
  ```

This is a boon and a curse sometimes. Assume if we are sending useState's [setState function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#updating-state) to the child, and in the child, we have a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)(that makes a network call to fetch data) that takes this function as its dependency. Now, for every state change in parent, even if there is a use-case or not, the useEffect will get triggered as this function in dependency is changed (as every update re-initializes the functions). To avoid this, we can utilize [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) on the functions which we want to memorize and change only when certain params are changed, but it is not advisable to use this on [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)'s callback function since we might end-up in stale values.

Further Reading:

1. [GeeksForGeeks useCallback](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/react-js-usecallback-hook/)
2. [SourceCode interpretation of useEffect](https://www.the-guild.dev/blog/react-hooks-system)
3. [Another SourceCode interpretation of useEffect](https://programming.vip/docs/source-code-interpretation-of-react-useeffect.html)

Answer (score 0):

First off, every react component has [memory cells](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components) associated with it. These memory cells hold information, which can persist during multiple renders. One example of this is the initial state set by `useState` hook. E.g.

```
function Test() {
  const [firstState, setFirstState] = useState("initial");
  ...
}
```

Note that react remembers states in the order they were defined(arrays behind the scenes). So `MemoryCell[0]` which correspond to `firstState`'s value will hold `"initial"`. Now a call to `setState("newState")` would update the memory cell for the first state variable(firstState) and will trigger a re render and execute `Test`'s body again and causally execute `const [state, setState] = useState("initial");` again as well. Now at this point React.useState doesn't make `firstState` equal to `"initial"` again, because react  checks it's memory cell for `firstState` variable and if `MemoryCell[0] != undefined` then `useState` returns `[MemoryCell[0], setStateClosure]`.

Now in the context of your question, one could think that `useEffect` uses a similar approach to store it's callback in the component's memory. E.g.

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  function foo(){}; //gets access to count
  useEffect(foo); // does it store foo in component's memory 
  // and checks if foo exist in memory on further render?
}
```

Now one could think that on first render `useEffect(foo)` stores `foo` in `MemoryCell["effect"][0]` and on every render(say `setCount()` is called) it does this:

```
if (`MemoryCell["effect"][0]` != undefined) {
  MemoryCell["effect"][0] = foo; //call it Memory_foo
}
```

Now if the above was true, that would emulate your proposal, that `useEffect` uses same callback function on every render. The problem with that is exactly what the docs mentioned:

> ...this is what lets us read the count value from inside the effect without worrying about it getting **stale**.

By stale they mean old value. `Memory_foo` sees `count`'s value same as it saw when `foo` was defined in the first render -- this is how closures work. Every new render redefines foo and that new foo will have access to the value of `count` as it saw during that render. For `useEffect` to perform proper side effects we always need correct(updated) state values in `Memory_foo`. As a proof of fact I have created the following example, which emulates `Memory_foo` and prints old(stale) `count` value:

```js
var renderCount = 0;

function example(countState) {
  var innerCountState = countState;

  function foo() { //effectCallback
    console.log(innerCountState);
  }
  if (renderCount === 0) {
    //similar to useEffect(foo) saving foo in component memory only on first render
    //similar to MemoryCell["effect"][0]` != undefined, because for renderCount > 0, it will be defined
    example.foo = foo; //similar to MemoryCell["effect"][0] = foo
  }
  renderCount++;
  return "<div> Counter is " + countState + "</div>";
}

console.log(example(1));
example.foo(); //emulate side effect after render

console.log(example(2));
example.foo(); //logs 1 which is old countState value
```

This proves the fact that passing same function to useEffect on every render will read wrong(old/stale) count value from inside the effect